# Can someone tell me if these commands are wrong?

Tags: command-line

I'm taking a class called UNIX/Linux Server. I've been asked to install Ubuntu 14.04.1, which went fine, and I got through some hands on projects but I'm getting stuck here: I type the command but it doesn't work. The command is

```
 ls /var/log/anaconda
```

The result I get is

```
ls: cannot access /var/log/anaconda: No such file or directory
```

What do I do?

The second command I'm having problems with is this command,

```
apt-get -y install build-essential gawkzlib1g-dev uuid-dev vim-nox python-software-properties
```

It's unable to locate the package, what should I do?

Comment: Well, at least `gawkzlib1g-dev` should be two separate packages `gawk` and `zlib1g-dev`. The only `anaconda` I know of is the [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) scientific python distribution - I can't see why that should write to `/var/log` though. Perhaps you should ask your instructor or teacher to clarify?

Comment: those are entirely separate issues, so your question is too broad

Comment: Anaconda is the RHEL/CentOS/Fedora installer

Comment: @heynnema I don't believe I close-voted this question

Comment: @heynnema nothing about your answer shows why two unrelated problems should be in one post

Comment: @heynnema I did not vtc. I just made the one comment.

Answer (score 5):

## Class Notes

- `ls /var/log/anaconda`

The `ls` command is the **list directory** command. It is used to show what files are located in any particular directory. In your command, `/var/log` is the directory that you're looking into, and `anaconda` is the filename, or directory, that you're looking for. Since that filename, or directory, doesn't exist on your system, you get the error. To see what else is in that directory, type `ls /var/log`.

- `apt-get -y install build-essential gawkzlib1g-dev uuid-dev vim-nox python-software-properties`

The `apt-get` command is the **APT package handling utility**. In your command the `install` is trying to install a number of packages. You're getting an error because one of your packages doesn't exist in the repositories. But which one? Here's one easy way to figure it out. Try breaking up the long list of packages to install, down to single items. Like so:

```
apt-get -y install build-essential
apt-get -y install gawkzlib1g-dev  <-- this one is the problem
apt-get -y install uuid-dev
apt-get -y install vim-nox
apt-get -y install python-software-properties
```

What you'll find out is that the second command shows you where your error is. Turns out that no such package `gawkzlib1g-dev` exists! But that gives you some information to go and figure out what's wrong. Well, it's because there's a package called `gawk` and another one called `zlib1g-dev` and **all that was wrong in your original command was that you forgot a space between those two package names!**

Answer (score 2):

Use the command `apt-cache search keyword` to display the available packages that you have in your system. Replace `keyword` with the name of the package.

If APT is unable to find a package it may be because the package list is not up to date. You can fix this by running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If it still can't be found, and you're sure you typed the name correctly, then it is not available in your current repositories, so try adding more repositories. If that doesn't work, the package may not be available for the version of Ubuntu you are using.

Be aware that if you try to install multiple packages in a single command, the whole command will fail, and nothing will be installed, if any one of the requested packages is not found.

About the first command, `ls` shows you the files and folders you have in a directory. From the output, it's clear that there's no a file called anaconda in `/var/log/`, as there's nothing wrong with the command you entered.